# make array of names php

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, names

I am trying to create a memberlist with all the members in the databse, however they are in there on a front name basis. So I an trying to put the surname first before printing them.

For that I wrote this function:

```
function surname($name){
    $exploded = explode(" ", $name);
    $num = count($exploded);

    $move = $exploded[$num - 1];
    unset($exploded[$num - 1]);
    array_unshift($exploded, $move);
    $name = implode(", ", $exploded);
    return $name;
}
```

And while using that I am trying to make an array of rightly called people. (because mysql sorts by front name instead of surname, so I want to sort the array aftarwards)

```
                $names = array();
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM Members";
                $self = mysql_query($sql);
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($self)) {
                    $name = $row["name"];
                    $name = surname($name);
                    array_push($names, $name);
                }               
                echo $names;
```

This however doesn't give anything back, which I think is because the array is being remade every loop.

So my question, is this a valid way of doing it or do I have to do something completely different?

Please help.

Comment: With regex you can make that `surname` function a simple one liner: `return preg_replace('/(\w+)\s+?(\w+)/','$2, $1',$name);`

Comment: But that only works if there are just 2 words right? The names I have can have 2 or more. (I think 4 is the current max, but I want to stay open for people with crazy names)

Comment: Names are practically impossible to validate, what would you expect from "Miguel Perez de Francisco" for example? My code above is flawed, but so is every other solution, because names are unpredictable. Ideally you'd have 2 different fields, one for name and one for last name(s) and store them separately in the DB, but seems like is too late to do that...

Comment: That one would be `Francisco, Miguel Perez de` and yea I'm a bit too late with the names :P

Comment: See, that name I would expect `Perez de Franscisco, Miguel`, but yeah I guess it's too late. If this is not trivial I would just take the time and "fix" the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this may work note its untested though

`SELECT * FROM Members ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ' ', -2)`

It should select the first 2 words that appear to the right of the first space. That should allow for middle name and surname.

OK this'll work too its messy/compute heavy but works.  Its horrible with loop within loop but short of fixing your db to a proper structure this is as good as you'll get (unless you wanna go into the black magic of regex.

```
$surnamesarray = array();
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM Members";
                $self = mysql_query($sql);
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($self)) {
                    $temparray = explode(" ",$row['name']);
                    $substring = "";
                    for ($i=0;$i<count($temparray);$i++) {
                     $substring .= " ".$temparray[$i];
                    }
                    $surnamesarray[] = trim($substring)
                }

// now we just array sort so 
sort($surnamesarray);
var_dump($surnamesarray);//you would now for each this array again to display i'm just dumping out here
```

Comment: But what if they don't have a middle name? And some have 2 like "Van Der"

Comment: it'll still work it'll match upto 2 entries after the space if you need to allow for 3 names (I thought van-der was always hyphonated proves how much I know) change it to -3 or -4 or -5 if you want to be really safe.

Comment: It only seems to get the ones that match it exactly. so the ones that are 3 long work all others don't

Comment: not sure then you'd probs have to regex it in query or out of query

Answer (score 0):

in your loop, change the second `$name` to `$names[]` then don't echo but `print_r($names)` and try deleting the array push